# Wave function of a particle in a gravitational field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

> *Suppose we have a particle with mass $m$ and energy $E$ in a gravitational field $V(z)=-mgz$. How can I find the wave function $\psi(z)$?*

It should have an integral form on $dp$. Any help would be appreciated.

**What I've tried**

One way to solve the problem is use of change of variable
$$
x~:=~\left(\frac{\hbar^2}{2m^2g}\right)^{2/3}\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}(mgz-E)
$$

we can reduce Schroedinger equation to

$$
\frac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}-x\phi(x)~=~0
$$

This is a standard equation, its solution is given by
$$\phi(x)~=~B~\text{Ai}(x)$$
where $\text{Ai}$ is the [Airy function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function). But my solution should be (not exactly) like this:

$$
\psi(z)= N\int_{-\infty}^\infty dp \exp\left[\left(\frac{E}{mg}+z\right)p-\frac{p^3}{6m^2g} \right]
$$

Comment: Seems like a straight-forward application of Schroedinger's equation. What have you tried?

Comment: I have solved it by WKB approximation but my answer do not coincide with what it should be in test.

Comment: Perhaps, then, you should show what you *did* do, so we can point out what you had done wrong.

Comment: Wavefunction of a particle in linearly changing potential is given by Airy functions.

Comment: Yes I know i was editing while you said.

Comment: This [Wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function#Fourier_transform) should be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\left[\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(i\hbar\frac{d}{dp})\right]\phi(p)=E\phi(p)
$$
$$
\left[\frac{p^2}{2m}+(-mg)(i\hbar\frac{d}{dp})\right]\phi(p)=E\phi(p)
$$
$$
\frac{1}{i\hbar mg}(\frac{p^2}{2m}-E)\phi(p)=\frac{\phi(p)}{dp}
$$
When integrate we have:
$$
\frac{i}{\hbar mg}(Ep-\frac{p^3}{6m})=Ln\frac{\phi(p)}{\phi(p_{o})}
$$
$$
\phi(p)=\phi(p_{0})e^{\frac{E}{mg}p-\frac{p^3}{6m^2g}}
$$
$$
\psi(z)=\int dp e^{ipz/\hbar} \phi(p)
$$
$$
\psi(z)=\phi(p_{0})\int_{-\infty}^\infty dp e^{i/\hbar \left[ (\frac{E}{mg}+z)p-\frac{p^3}{6m^2g}\right]}
$$

Comment: why -1?  it seems to be true!

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea for this is to use the *momentum* space version of the Schroedinger equation:
$$
\hat{p}\to p,\quad\hat{x}\to i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial p}
$$
and then solve the system<sup>1</sup>,
$$
\left[\frac{p^2}{2m}+img\hbar\frac{d}{dp}\right]\phi=E\phi
$$

which should be solvable (e.g., complex exponentials). You can then [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Definition) to physical space to get
$$
\psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int dp\,e^{ipx/\hbar}\phi(p)
$$
This should match to what your professor expects.

---

<sup>More formally/generalized, you should get$$
\frac{p^2}{2m}\phi\left(p\right)+\int dp'\,U\left(p-p'\right)\phi\left(p'\right)=E\phi\left(p\right)$$
where
$$U(p)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int dx\,e^{-ipx/\hbar}U(x)$$
but this will reduce to the above anyway</sup>

Comment: I agree, I tried this method as well but I thought it was a bit odd.It should be solvable with more effort. Let me think more. Thank you.

Comment: @Abolfazl: two things to note to combine as a single hint: (1) $\frac{d}{dx}\exp[f(x)]=\exp[f(x)]\cdot\frac{df}{dx}$ and (2) your teachers solution has a $p^3$ term in it.

Comment: I think we can use this form of Airy function 
$$
Ai(t)=\frac{1}{{2\pi i}}\int dp\,exp(\frac{p^3}{3}-tp)
$$ 
,[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function#Fourier_transform),
where $t=mgz+E$

Comment: @Abolfazl: I would argue that you don't need to know the Airy function at all. So just completely forget that it was mentioned. Start by using a trial wave-function (in momentum space) of the form $\tilde{\phi}(p)=A\exp\left[f(p)\right]$ and see what *conditions* are required on $f(p)$ to satisfy this.